# Только что созданный файл занят другим процессом и я не могу его удалить

Tags: c#, файлы, исключения, io, delete

```
File.Delete(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SYS\Monitor.syst");
File.Create(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SYS\Monitor.syst");
File.Delete(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SYS\Monitor.syst");
```

Использую такую конструкцию, чтобы удалить файл, создать и удалить. Изначально файл есть. На 3 строчке вылетает исключение, мол файл занят процессом уже. Объясните, как пофиксить это, и в чем ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что  `File.Create` возвращает `Stream` для работы с файлом.

Вызовите `Close` или `Dispose` после создания и тогда файл не будет занят.

Да, у стримов реализован финализатор => через какое-то время его сборщик мусор сам прибьет, но когда это будет и будет ли вообще неизвестно => лучше самому закрыть ресурс.

Comment: или используйте `using(File.Create(...));`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит использовать

```
using(var fileStream = File.Create(...))
{
   // ваш код
}
```

при завершении `using` вызовется `Dispose`.