# При удалении картинки после использования в WPF, ошибка, что файл занят другим процессом

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, c#-8.0

Есть окно WPF, где находятся Image и Button, Source на Image вешается через код, при нажатии на Button, Source у Image приравнивается null и удаляется, но при удалении через код выдаётся ошибка, что файл занят другим процессом. Как мне в итоге удалить файл через код?

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\\test.png"));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.Source = null; 
        File.Delete("D:\\test.png");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFImageCheck.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFImageCheck"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="129" Width="327" FontSize="72" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Image x:Name="Image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="206" Margin="219,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Можете попробовать удалить файл через extern метод `DeleteFile` библиотеки kernel32 (http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/DeleteFile.html?diff=y). Тем не менее, если вы не хотите это делать - попробуйте вызвать `File.Exists` (проверка существования файла). Так же, проверьте, не забываете ли вы закрывать файл после его прочтения. Отлично будет, если вы обернёте чтение в `using` (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1048886/378277)

Comment: Файл всегда существует, так как используется для отображения на Image, и как завернуть присваивание png к Image через using?

Comment: А, прошу прощения - думал, что вы открываете файл и читаете его. В таком случае, сделайте по аналогии: http://tedshelloworld.blogspot.com/2010/11/bitmaps-in-wpf-disposing-of-bitmaps-in.html или вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/16908562/13123688. Точь-в-точь ситуация, как у вас

Comment: Ситуация не изменилась

Comment: Но узнал то, что через секунд 5 программа отпускает файл и его можно удалить, но искусственно замедлять программу это довольно плохое решение (хоть и рабочее)

Comment: Значит стоит отказаться от такого подхода и попробовать считать данные из файла в переменную и после этого только удалять. Нашёл решение через storageFile: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/522406/bitmapimage-delete-cannot-access-the-file-because.html https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257504/13123688. Никогда с ним не работал, но выглядит убедительно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16908562

Comment: Странный вопрос, а зачем удалять? Налицо ошибка проектирования, но исправить можно только поняв, а в чем, собственно суть задачи заключается? Как эта картинка вообще на диске оказалась? Всё предложенное выше - костыли разной степени тяжести. Кажется, надо исправлять не удаление файла, а его появление там. Не будет файла - не будет проблемы удаления, автоматически.

Comment: Вообще у меня цель такая - есть окно, где есть картинки, мне нужно поменять файлы картинок, что бы в программе они тоже изменились, но я банально не могу заменить эти картинки, так как они заняты другим процессом

Comment: А зачем картинки на диске трогать? Надо в интерфейсе менять - там и меняйте. Мало деталей, надо больше.

Comment: Помогло создание всех картинок этим способом:
stackoverflow.com/a/16908562

Comment: Вы меня не вслышали, ну ок. Если что, при такой загрузке изображений, окно виснет намертво на время загрузки. Если уж на то пошло, можно был бы загрузиться в массив бай и потом привязать контрол к массиву. А файл с диска прочитать асинхронно. Могу показать, как, если интересно.

Comment: Ну кстати не виснет при смене картинок